$D = \ker(dx_3 - x_1 dx_2) \cap \ker (dx_1 - x_4 dx_2) \subset T \mathbb R^4$ is a distribution of rank two. Determine whether $D$ is integrable.
This question is from a publicly available old qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. I used Lee's textbook for conceptual help with this problem, but I didn't see any proof or example that I could directly use. All work is thus my own.


$$D = \ker(dx_3 - x_1 dx_2) \cap \ker (dx_1 - x_4 dx_2) \subset T \mathbb R^4$$ is a distribution of rank two. Determine whether $D$ is integrable.

From the first part of this question, the kernel is computed as a vector field of form:
$$V = (\alpha + \delta \, x_4 ) \partial x_1 + (\beta + \delta ) \partial x_2 + (\beta \, x_1 + \varepsilon) \partial x_3 + (\gamma + \zeta) \partial x_4 \; $$
From the Frobenius theorem, our distribution if integrable $\iff$ it is involutive. Our distribution is involutive if the Lie bracket of any two vector fields in our distribution is still in the distribution. For
$$ V = (v_\alpha + v_\delta \, x_4 ) \partial x_1 + (v_\beta + v_\delta ) \partial x_2 + (v_\beta \, x_1 + v_\varepsilon) \partial x_3 + (v_\gamma + v_\zeta) \partial x_4 $$
and
$$ W = (w_\alpha + w_\delta \, x_4 ) \partial x_1 + (w_\beta + w_\delta ) \partial x_2 + (w_\beta \, x_1 + w_\varepsilon) \partial x_3 + (w_\gamma + w_\zeta) \partial x_4 $$
we have that $$V(W) = (w_\beta) \partial x_3 + (w_\delta) \partial x_1$$
and $$W(V) = (v_\beta ) \partial x_3 + (v_\delta) \partial x_1$$
which implies
$$ \left [ V, W \right ] = V(W) - W(V) = (w_\delta - v_\delta ) \partial x_1 + (w_\beta - v_\beta) \partial x_3 $$
Setting the bases corresponding to $\partial x_2$ and $\partial x_4$ in the original $V$ vector to zero, we have
$$ V' = (\alpha + \delta x_4) \partial x_1 + (\beta x_1 + \varepsilon ) \partial x_3$$
Trivially, substituting
\begin{align}
& \alpha \mapsto w_\delta \\ & \delta \mapsto (-v_\delta / x_4) \\ & \beta \mapsto (w_\beta / x_1) \\ &\varepsilon \mapsto (- v_\beta)
\end{align}
we see that our distribution is involutive, and thus integrable.

(a) Did I correctly compute the kernel and Lie bracket? I haven't done a Lie Bracket computation before, so I want to make sure I did things correctly.
The recommended review material for the Stanford exam had the Frobenius theorem, so I assume this question was probably testing to make sure you knew it.
As a bonus: if there's a more efficient trick or more powerful method than using Frobenius theorem, then I'd love to see it.

When the distribution is given as the kernel of differential forms, you don’t need to mess around with vector fields. There’s a version of Frobenius’ theorem which is precisely adapted to this situation.

@peek-a-boo Is the differential forms kernel example given in Lee’s book? I read the chapter with Frobenius theorem in it, but I may have missed the example he gives with the kernel of forms? A link or page of a textbook ref would be appreciated.

Lee’s book, problem 19-2. (I thought it was proved in the main text). Henri Cartan’s book on differential forms has the proof as well.

@peek-a-boo Just got home. Taking exterior derivatives on our defining forms and applying Lee Problem 19-2's, computation: $ (- dx_1 \wedge dx_2) \wedge (x_4 dx_2) = (x_1 dx_2) \wedge (dx_4 \wedge dx_2) = 0$, therefore involutive and therefore integrable?

Computation seems wrong. You should have forms of degree $(n-k)+2$, which in your case is $4-2+2=4$, but you only have $3$-forms.

[Lee] Page 494: Local defining forms that induce a kernel are of cardinality $\omega^1 \dots \omega^{n-k}$. For us, $n = 4, k=2$, and we have two defining forms. Satisfied. Then for question 19-2, we only need to satisfy $d \omega^i \wedge  (\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2)$ for all $i$. This will give us two 3-forms $dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge x_1 dx_2 \wedge \cdots = 0$ and $dx_4 \wedge dx_2 \wedge x_4 dx_2 \wedge \cdots = 0$. I see no reference in Lee to your rank criteria.

Count again. What is the degree of the form $d\omega_i \wedge (\omega_1\wedge \omega_2)$? And more generally $d\omega_i \wedge (\omega_1\wedge\cdots \wedge \omega_{n-k})$?

@peek-a-boo You're right. Those are 4-forms instead of $3$ if I were to expand the $(\cdots)$. Still, the wedge product goes to zero, and involutivity is satisfied, no?

I didn’t do the calculation (and you didn’t do it correctly above in the comments either), so just double check your work. Compute $\omega_1\wedge \omega_2$ carefully, then compute $d\omega_i$ carefully and their wedge product.
